# How can I best document my answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

I created a 2015+ answer to a question for a specific driver from 2010, but I feel like it will be where 90% of web traffic goes. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42589110/931280 It was swiftly deleted, but some feedback would be really helpful.

[image: Deleted answer]

I'm guessing I should create a new question and answer it myself?

Comment: Imagine the link died, would it be a useful answer? Additionally, the question is who is refreshing the watchdog? Your answer does not seem to address that. Same as what?

Comment: @RobertLongson It doesn't look entirely dependant on the link to me.  The link is supplemental to the point it's trying to make.  And it not successfully answering the question would be a reason to downvote, not a reason to delete.

Comment: Indeed, presumably it was flagged as link-only but it is a little more than that. You could custom flag it for undeletion but in its current state you'd likely attract downvotes.

Comment: To me it seems like it would be useful as a comment to the question. It isn't necessarily an answer to the OP (they're using a much older version,) but it would be a useful link for anyone viewing the question today.

Comment: You could include an explanation of what "the same behavior" means, and what the change means with regard to the question.

Comment: @Kevin B Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to comment :)

Comment: @Tiny Giant Good point.

Comment: @RobertLongson I originally made an edit to the answer I was referring to, but that was rejected too. I will clarify with a verbal link to that answer.

Comment: What is the place to put my more clear answer? Should I make a new answer or edit the old one?

Comment: Just edit your old answer and flag it for undeletion. You can let us know here once you've edited it so that we can review it for you again before you flag for undeletion if you like

Comment: Rewrote it, and flagged for undeletion, but it says ~ "moderator deleted it, can't undelete". Also, I can't link it directly here as it's hidden. And the comment field is too short. So...I'll post it below?

Comment: You'll need to use the "flag" link and write out a little explanation in the box under the "needs moderator intervention" option.

Comment: Whoops, that fixes it. Thanks @JoshCaswell

Comment: If you need to comment, get the reputation to comment then do so, don't misuse answers as comments.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for the helpful comments. It sounds like I'm supposed to rewrite my original answer to protect against link rot and better clarify what "the same behavior" means. Below is my rewritten answer.

> In July 2016 [a commit in the 4.7 kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/3fbfe9264756d3fd99a9210345016c94ec4ada73) to watchdog_dev.c enabled the same behavior as shodanex's answer for all watchdog timer drivers. This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere other than this thread and the source code.
>
> ```
> /*
> * A worker to generate heartbeat requests is needed if all of the
> * following conditions are true.
> * - Userspace activated the watchdog.
> * - The driver provided a value for the maximum hardware timeout, and
> *   thus is aware that the framework supports generating heartbeat
> *   requests.
> * - Userspace requests a longer timeout than the hardware can handle.
> *
> * Alternatively, if userspace has not opened the watchdog
> * device, we take care of feeding the watchdog if it is
> * running.
> */
>
> return (hm && watchdog_active(wdd) && t > hm) ||
>        (t && !watchdog_active(wdd) && watchdog_hw_running(wdd));
> ```

Additionally it would be more appropriate to make a new question entirely, as parts of the original question (why a reset at 15 minutes) were never solved and adding irrelevant information to the conversation wouldn't help.

Comment: The edited answer still doesn't actually answer the question, any more than the original did.  It doesn't merit deletion, but it's still a bad answer.

Comment: it what servy says is true, then yes, ask your own question and answer it. Google will find it fast (a day or two)